# Machine learning in Time series analysis

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, pattern-recognition

I will like to do classifiaction with unsupervised learning where the input is a time series. Each sample consisting of 5000 datapoints.

Most people doing time series analysis are interested in forecasting, but I am primarly interested in unsupervised classification (Later I will introduce labels to do supervised classification).

Any good suggestions to how to do that. Does not look smart to feed these 5.000 values into a K-mean clustering

Answer (score 1):

Most common clustering approaches require a distance metric to be defined between your samples. Essentially, how do you know that two samples are similar and should be in the same cluster? Some starting points for defining such metrics could be [Alternate distance metrics for two time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185912/alternate-distance-metrics-for-two-time-series) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497756/time-series-distance-metric

Once you have an appropriate distance metric, most common clustering algorithms should work "out-of-the-box" in the same way as they would work on non-time-series data.

Comment: It may be a little complicated. The signal (an electrocardiogram) consist of 10 sec sampled with 500 hz. It consist of repeating cyclic events starting randomly in time. There number of events during the 10 sec vary from lets say 5-20 events. The more events the shorter each event are, so a distance measure may not be the best way, simply because it is impossible to implement

Comment: @JørgenK.Kanters But you need some measure of similarity or closeness between your samples to perform clustering. Imagine that you have a model that has partitioned your samples into N clusters. How would you know if the model has done a good job? Presumably because samples within clusters are somehow "more similar" than samples between clusters, right? A quantification of that similarity measure would be your distance metric. There can be infinitely many such distance metrics - how is your ML algorithm supposed to guess which one you are interested in?

Comment: @JørgenK.Kanters It seems that a good start could be to normalize your samples to have the same number of events within them and the same length - assuming periodicity is not important (or you could encode it separately). That should make your time series comparable, so that you could use e.g. correlation as your distance metric. But it really all depends on what kind of similarity measure is important for you, i.e. domain knowledge.

Comment: That is the problem. periodicity is important. Furhermore the subfeatures of the signal have different variations dependent of the event rate/frequency. So scaling is absolutely not trivial. Thats why my initial step would be unsupervised learning, so I could let the ML itself find putative similarities. I could then look at the output classifications to see if it found something interesting. the main problem is that the different parts of the cyclic events means something different. But our first try will be as you suggested. We will try scale the signal and use som distance measures

Comment: @JørgenK.Kanters "Thats why my initial step would be unsupervised learning, so I could let the ML itself find putative similarities" - this is problematic without a definition of "similarity" or examples of similarities. The latter case would mean using supervised learning. Otherwise the problem is ill-defined and ML will be of no help.