# Is there a distance metric between ordered vectors?

Tags: time-series, distance-functions, vector-fields

I am looking for a distance metric between vectors whose elements are ordered,
i.e so the vectors:

[1,5,0,0,0,0,1], [1,0,4,0,0,1,0]

will be considered closer than

[1,5,0,0,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1,5,0,0]

for example if you perform pacf on a time series you get the importance of the lags on the time series, where the first elements represent 1 lag, the second element 2 lags etc. Naturally if for one time series lag 10 is important and for another it is 11, they are closer than 10 and 15 are...

Is there a metric like that? are vectors like that still called vectors or do they have another name?

edit:
a simpler example:

[1,0,0,0,0] should be closer to [0,1,0,0,0] than to [0,0,0,0,1]

the index of the elements should be taken into account...

Comment: That's usually how it's done, for ex. Euclidean distance is calculated pairwise.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I don't want it to be calculated pairwise because if the pair is off by 1 they are considered completely distant. e.g. [1,0,0,0,0] is as far from [0,1,0,0,0] as it is from [0,0,0,0,1]. That's not what I want.. in my vectors the order of the elements in the vector is meaningful, so if you have high values with close indices to one another (but not identical), they should be considered closer.

Comment: [Alternate distance metrics for two time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185912/alternate-distance-metrics-for-two-time-series)

Comment: [Time series distance metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497756/time-series-distance-metric)

Comment: A standard metric with this property is determined by the lexicographic ordering of these vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Earth Mover's Distance does exactly what you want. It moves all data ("dirt") from the first vector into the second such that the amount of dirt moved times the dsitance is minimal.

Applying its R implementation on your data yields (the first column in the data represents the value, the second the spatial location, which is the index in your case):

```
> library(emdist)
> A <- cbind(c(1,5,0,0,0,0,1),1:7)
> B <- cbind(c(1,0,4,0,0,1,0),1:7)
> C <- cbind(c(1,0,0,1,5,0,0),1:7)
> emd(A,B)
[1] 0.8333333
> emd(A,C)
[1] 2.285714
```

Comment: I tried it with the python implementation and it didn't do what I wanted... the EMD didn't seem to care about how far I have to move the 5. if you try emd when you replace the 4 in B with 5 for me it gave a 0 distance, and that's how I understand the metric... which isn't right either...

Comment: Hm, I do not obtain 0 when I replace the 4 in B with a 5, but 0.857. Conceptually, the EMD assumes that the data has been normalized to sum up to one (in other words: the data represents distributions), but principlally the algorithm also works for non-normalized data.

Comment: Just an idea: I had the same problem of obtaining zero at the beginning, because I had not understand the interface: the data must be presentied in *two columns* (not rows!), with the index as the second column. Maybe you have inadvertantly created a transposed matrix?

Comment: I'll check it out, Thank you, fyi,  so far this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497756/time-series-distance-metric let me to the best solutions. The idea is simple - transform the data to cumsum and then use any distance metric. It's also the idea behind Kolmogorov–Smirnov test, which can be applied here as well.

Comment: a = np.array([1,5,0,0,0,0,1])
b = np.array([1,0,5,0,0,0,1])
wasserstein_distance(a, b)
[1] 0
And I was told this makes sense... I don't know the metric very well..